# python rename all files in subdirectories

Tags: python

i have two folder and each folder has six file with different extension (.txt, .jpg, .tiff etc) and i want to rename each file name with same name (don't want to change file extension) using Python.

could please help me out. I am new to programming and am starting to learn Python

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Emtiaj, could you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Renaming to the same name isn't possible unless all 6 files are different types. Attempt something and we can then help you.

Comment: Check my answer below! and see if it helps you!

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it helps you! @EmtiajHoque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all files in the directory using [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), and then use [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)
to rename all files, also use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to extract extension and file name

```
import os

folder_name = '<folder_where_we_have_files>'
name = '<name_for_file>'
for file in os.listdir(folder_name):
    #Get the full file path
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, file)
    #Get the file name and it's extension
    file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    #We don't want to rename file which is already renamed
    if name not in file_name:
        #Create the full path of the new file
        new_file = os.path.join(folder_name, name + extension)
        #Rename the file to new file
        os.rename(file_path, new_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder_name):
    src=foldername+filename
    dst=new_name+filename.split(".")[1]
    dst=folder_name+dst
    os.rename(src,dst)
```